# Convert a hex string into an unsigned decimal value

Tags: vb.net, hex, unsigned

I want to convert an hex string into an unsigned value? How can I to do that?

Here's my code (not working):

```
address_2_WR_data1="0000F000"
az = ((Val("&H" & address_2_WR_data1)))
```

but the result is that: az=FFFFF000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToUInt32` to convert a hex string to an unsigned integer.

```
Dim address_2_WR_data1 As String = "F000F000"
Dim az As UInt32 = Convert.ToUInt32(address_2_WR_data1, 16)
```